# Report estimate items

Tags: printing, quickbooks

I need to print individual estimate items in QuickBooks on separate packing stickers with company and item information, one sticker for each item. I have created a print format as an Estimate template with the desired information but it only retrieves the first item of the estimate. I need the same form to print all items on separate stickers using the same template.

A related problem is that Printer Setup establishes the default Estimate printer, which apparently can be different for each user in a multi-user situation but only allows the same Estimate printer for all formats of a single user. I would like to establish a default printer for each Estimate format of an individual user (I print estimates in several formats and want to use different printers - e.g. a page printer and a sticker printer).

Comment: Do you have some code that you can post, or is this just a question about the actual operation (use) of QuickBooks? If it's the first, please [edit] and post the code that isn't working for you; if it's the second, your question is off-topic here (the [help#ontopic] pages can give you information about the types of questions that are appropriate for StackOverflow).